# How to call class method within namespace of the same class in python 3.x

Tags: python, class-method

When working with python instances, it is possible to access bound methods of the same class using `self`. This resolves to a method corresponding to the same class in hierarchy.

```py
class A:
    def f(self):
        return 1

    def __init__(self):
        self.v = self.f()

class B(A):
    def f(self):
        return 2

b = B()
# b.v is set to 2
```

But, when working with class methods, there is no apparent way of accessing methods of the same class as above.

In my use case, `f` above needs to be a class method and I need to set class variable `v` according to `f` corresponding to the same class. Somewhat like:

```py
class A:
    @classmethod
    def f(cls):
        return 1

    v = resolution_of_calling_class.f()

class B(A):
    @classmethod
    def f(cls):
        return 2

# B.v should be 2
```

**edit**: `v` is actually an attribute defined by parent class, which should find a method overridden by child class

Comment: I don't think that I understand your use case; perhaps you could make sure to clarify in the post when you are referring to a superclass or a subclass.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity in original question. I've tried to make it more clear. I'm trying to find the `resolution_of_calling_class` as described in the second snippet, similar to `self` in the first snippet refers to calling class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to override `__new__` method, since it is invoked before the `__init__` and its purpose is to create an instance, that will be initialized by `__init__`.

```py
class A:

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        cls.v = cls.f()
        return super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

    @classmethod
    def f(cls):
        return 1


class B(A):
    @classmethod
    def f(cls):
        return 2


a = A()
print(a.v)

b = B()
print(b.v)
```

```py
1
2
```

Comment: Hi, that's an useful answer! I think I implemented this using Mixin pattern in my actual implementation. But this really answers the question!

Comment: @PushkarNimkar Nice!

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure I understand what you are trying to do.

I used your code above and

```
class A:
    @classmethod
    def f(cls):
        return 1

class B:
    @classmethod
    def f(cls):
        return 2

print(B.f())
```

gives me 2 just as I expected it would.  Should B be a child class of A as in the first example?

Comment: Yes B should be a child class of A as in the first example.